# obtener texto de wp_editor en wordpress

Tags: wordpress

tengo un `wp_editor` y cuando hago clic en enviar llamo a una funcion javascript que toma los campos `titulo`, y el texto del `wp_editor`.

```
<div class="form-group">
<?php
   wp_editor( $content,'id_contenido',array('textarea_name' => 
 'contenido','editor_class'=>'form-control'));?>
</div>
```

el tema es que quiero obtener el texto escrito en el editor para mandarlo por ajax y guardarlo en la bd, pero me da undefined o vacio...
asi intento tomarlo

```
$("#id_contenido").val();
```

Alguien sabe porque siempre me da vació? gracias

Comment: En el inspector de elementos, aparece con el ID correcto? Cómo/Cuándo estás detectando el valor?

Comment: <div id="mceu_29" class="mce-edit-area mce-container mce-panel mce-stack-layout-item" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" role="group" style="border-width: 1px 0px 0px;"><iframe id="id_contenido_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Área de texto enriquecido. Pulsa Alt-Shift-H para obtener ayuda." style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;"></iframe></div>

eso es lo que me genera, no se bien como trabaja el wp_editor, no es un campo de texto comun, o un text area

Comment: me alegra que lo hayas podido solucionar. Lo ideal sería que pongas tu solución como respuesta a tu pregunta, en vez de como comentario, así otros pueden verlo fácilmente y aprovechar el conocimiento.

Comment: No encuentro como ponerlo como solución....

Comment: Abajo, en el campo de "Tu respuesta"

Answer (score 0):

Es porque está dentro de un iframe y se hace un poco complicado. No obstante te dejo una función que te servira:

```
function get_tinymce_content(idWrap){
if (jQuery(idWrap).hasClass("tmce-active")){
    return tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
}else{
    return jQuery('#tinymce').val();
}
```

}

Donde idWrap = #id_contenido